# Set cookie after certain time delay (in PHP)

Tags: php, cookies

I'd like to set a cookie in PHP for my website visitors after they have been on my site for at least 2 minutes.

I guess the sleep() function could do just that, but I read that it might delay loading of the entire page.

Is there any other way to this?

Comment: `sleep` is useless.

Comment: surely you can research this; there's a lot of stuff out there including manuals; the *official* ones.

Comment: *"Is there any other way to this?"* - Yes; check if it's set and passed the 2 minute mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ajax request from the `JavaScript` which will load a `PHP` file after 2 minutes.

**In JS:**

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        // create the AJAX request to set_the_cookie.php
    }, 120000);
</script>
```

Information about [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

**In PHP (set_the_cookie.php):**

```
<?php
    $value = 'yours_value';
    setcookie('cookie_name', $value);
?>
```